# Get Value of LinkButton at ServerSide , which has been set by javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am setting value of the LinkButton using javascript using ..

```
 window.opener.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtTestChargeLocation_0").innerHTML = val;
```

Although I am able to chage the text of the LinkButton, I am not able to access the value at the server side.

I am however able to access the value if I use TextBox instead of LinkButton and using `Value property`..

```
 window.opener.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtTestChargeLocation_0").value = val;
```

I do not want to use any HiddenFields. I just want to use LinkButton.

Comment: i dont think that link button has any value property. link button have text value.so you can do like this window.opener.document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtTestChargeLocation_0").innerText = val;   @Arbaaz

Comment: only values of input are included in data POST to server in standard http. linkbutton is not an input. ajax using javascript can do that.   plain c# asp.net code have to use hidden field.

Comment: Isnt there a way to achieve this using Javascript or Jquery or something?

Comment: could you give the code of how you try to get link button value at server side.@Arbaaz